# Как сохранить параметры нормализации признаков

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, кластеризация

Есть Pandas DataFrame с именем Total_res. Нормирую часть признаков из него:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
Total_res[columns_for_norm] = preprocessing.normalize(Total_res[columns_for_norm])
```

Далее строю модель кластеризации.
Вопрос возникает на стадии появления новых записей, которые надо при помощи построенной модели отнести к одному из кластеров. 
Новые записи сохраняю в DataFrame New_rec. Для того, что бы передать эти данные построенной ранее модели их надо нормализовать.
Подозреваю, что недостаточно просто сделать

```
New_rec[columns_for_norm] = preprocessing.normalize(New_rec[columns_for_norm])
```

Думаю, что при при нормализации новых данных надо как-то учесть параметры нормализации исходного набора данных. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть.

Answer (score 2):

С нормализацией все достаточно просто - нормализируйте новые данные с такими же параметрами, которые вы использовали для нормализации начальных данных.

По поводу кластеризации новых данных все немного сложнее.
Для большинства алгоритмов кластеризации вам придется переобучать модель на полном наборе данных (с учетом новых данных).

Некоторые алгоритмы позволяют делать [Inductive Clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/cluster/plot_inductive_clustering.html).

Пример из документации:

```
# Authors: Chirag Nagpal
#          Christos Aridas
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, clone
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.utils.metaestimators import if_delegate_has_method


N_SAMPLES = 5000
RANDOM_STATE = 42


class InductiveClusterer(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, clusterer, classifier):
        self.clusterer = clusterer
        self.classifier = classifier

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.clusterer_ = clone(self.clusterer)
        self.classifier_ = clone(self.classifier)
        y = self.clusterer_.fit_predict(X)
        self.classifier_.fit(X, y)
        return self

    @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='classifier_')
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.classifier_.predict(X)

    @if_delegate_has_method(delegate='classifier_')
    def decision_function(self, X):
        return self.classifier_.decision_function(X)


def plot_scatter(X,  color, alpha=0.5):
    return plt.scatter(X[:, 0],
                       X[:, 1],
                       c=color,
                       alpha=alpha,
                       edgecolor='k')


# Generate some training data from clustering
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=N_SAMPLES,
                  cluster_std=[1.0, 1.0, 0.5],
                  centers=[(-5, -5), (0, 0), (5, 5)],
                  random_state=RANDOM_STATE)


# Train a clustering algorithm on the training data and get the cluster labels
clusterer = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3)
cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

plt.subplot(131)
plot_scatter(X, cluster_labels)
plt.title("Ward Linkage")


# Generate new samples and plot them along with the original dataset
X_new, y_new = make_blobs(n_samples=10,
                          centers=[(-7, -1), (-2, 4), (3, 6)],
                          random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

plt.subplot(132)
plot_scatter(X, cluster_labels)
plot_scatter(X_new, 'black', 1)
plt.title("Unknown instances")


# Declare the inductive learning model that it will be used to
# predict cluster membership for unknown instances
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
inductive_learner = InductiveClusterer(clusterer, classifier).fit(X)

probable_clusters = inductive_learner.predict(X_new)


plt.subplot(133)
plot_scatter(X, cluster_labels)
plot_scatter(X_new, probable_clusters)

# Plotting decision regions
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.1))

Z = inductive_learner.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.4)
plt.title("Classify unknown instances")

plt.show()
```

Comment: При нормализации исходных данных я не указываю никаких параметров. Просто пишу preprocessing.normalize(Total_res[columns_for_norm]). Как нормировать новые данные с такими же параметрами, как исходные?

Comment: @Green, в этом случае используются значения параметров по умолчанию. Если вызвать `normalize()` для новых данных тоже без параметров, то значения параметров по умолчанию будут такими же как и для обучающей выборки